# C++ Delete Objects of dynamic Array

Tags: c++, arrays, image, dynamic, bitmap

I am programming with the C++ Builder from Embarcadero.I created an TImage Array :

```
TImage *Image[c] ; // c is 5 

after that I am creating dynamic Images on an BUTTON CLICK :

for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) 
    {

    Image[i] = new TImage(this); 
    Image[i]->Parent = BoardItem ; // BoardItem is an Item of an TabControl    
    Image[i]->Height = 20 ;        
    Image[i]->Width = 20 ;        
    Image[i]->Position->X = d ;   // d and e are defined in the public var's.
    Image[i]->Position->Y = e ;
    Image[i]->Bitmap = Icon->Bitmap ; // Icon is an Image on my Formular
}
```

It's working fine but the Icon->Bitmap is from a Database , which is also working fine . But on an second Button Click the old Images are not deleted. So everytime when I'm clicking the button again, the program is creating 5 more Images but  the old ones are still there.

My question is now, how to refresh the old Images ? Should i delete the old Images an create then the new Images ? ( I tried this with  ( delete , Free () , delete[] Array, but im always getting a violence ERROR ) 
Or should i refresh the old Images, in case there are Updates on the Bitmaps of the Images in the Database, and how ?

Comment: Did you try a simple `delete Image[i];` from a loop?

Comment: [useless comment]: violence ERRORs are the worst! Sadly, though, I cannot help you here.

Comment: Yes i tried it but I am getting a acess violent error

Comment: Yes violence errors are hard cause sometimes it breaks my whole project xD

Answer (score 0):

You need two things:

- Make sure that the pointers are initialized to null the first time around:

  ```
  TImage* Image[c] = {};
  ```
- Delete the old image when you load a new one:

  ```
  delete Image[i];
  Image[i] = new TImage(this);
  ```

Note that using `delete` on a null pointer is perfectly safe; it just doesn't do anything.  So nothing changes on the first set of images, and each subsequent set automatically clears out the old ones instead of leaking.

Comment: Hopefully the destructor of Image does not delete the `Bitmap`?

Comment: @LokiAstari: I guess it's good if it does, as long as it is first detached from any GUI widget that is actively using it for painting.  Then the new bitmap can be reconstituted from the database and attached to the `Image` array and any widgets.

Comment: Well , thanks for the answer but the problem is when initialize the Image Array this Way : TImage* Image[c] = {}; i get an error that the object can not be initialized with a variable value. So i initialized it with 20 for example. Problem is i dont actually know how many i have to retrieve from the databse ( I got an Query which counts how many id's are in the database). And to the second point : I dont want to delete the old Images in the for loop i want to delete the old Images before the for loop. I tried it with another loop which is also counting to 5 and in it delete Image[(Variable)]

Answer (score -1):

@Ben Voigt here you got my whole Code hope you can understand it . Everytime i want to click the button the old images should be refreshed. To do that i want to delete the old an after that crate the new ones .

```
TImage *Image[20]= {} ;

for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) 
{
str = " Hallo "

Image[i] = new TImage(this);  
Image[i]->Parent = BoardItem ;  
Image[i]->Height = 20 ;  
Image[i]->Width = 20 ;   
Image[i]->Position->X = d ;  
Image[i]->Position->Y = e ; 
Image[i]->Bitmap = Icon->Bitmap ;  
Image[i]->StyleName = str ;     
Image[i]->OnClick = ImageClick ;
d = d + 20 ;   // the next Image should be x-Position +20

if (d == 367) {  // 367 is the Width of my Formular  
  d = 7 ;       // If it is 367 Position-x is 7 again und Position-y is +20 
  e = e + 20 ;   
 }
}
```