# C++ Builder Delete Objects of dynamic Array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++builder, timage

I want to delete old images I created in a for loop.

The first time clicking the Button the images are created. The second time or third, whatever, the old Images that were created should now be deleted (before the loop) and then directly recreated in the loop.

Because I am getting the `Image` properties from the database and when someone changed something in the database you should be enabled to get the newest Image properties from the database.

I tried it with `delete Image[i]`, `free()` and `delete[]` (whole Array) but I am always getting an *Access Violation Error*. Here is my following code:

```
TImage *Image[c]= ; //c is 5
```

I want to delete the old Images here and then create the new in the loop below

```
for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) 
{
str = " Test "

Image[i] = new TImage(this);  
Image[i]->Parent = BoardItem ;  
Image[i]->Height = 20 ;  
Image[i]->Width = 20 ;   
Image[i]->Position->X = d ;  // The program asks you the coordinate at the begining of a new loop
Image[i]->Position->Y = e ; 
Image[i]->Bitmap = Icon->Bitmap ;  
Image[i]->StyleName = str ;     
Image[i]->OnClick = ImageClick ;   
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you tried delete Image[i], free() and delete[] ?

Comment: simply a for loop like in code below

Comment: I ask, because delete Image[i] is the right way...

Comment: yes i know but I am getting an acess_violence error . When I am adding delete Image[i] at the end of the Loop where i create the Images , It works . But that is useless because I dont want to create the Images and directly delete them . I want to delete the before the Loop begins as you can see in my code . I just tried it with another loop. for int i = 0; i< c; i++ . And in the loop delete Image[i]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Delete Objects of dynamic Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34665307/c-delete-objects-of-dynamic-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must delete single image by simple `delete` operator like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
{
    delete Image[i];
    // NULL deleted pointer
    Image[i] = NULL;
}
```

Access Violation also may be caused because you still use this images somewhere in your code. And why did you want delete this images? As they are pointers you may simple renew values.

To reserve values for unpredictable amount of pointers `TImage*` you can use:

```
TImage** ppImage= NULL;
```

than create amount of pointers you want:

```
ppImage = new TImage*[c];
```

after that you may work with those pointers like you did before.

Comment: Well you might be right with renew values , cause that is simply what i want to do but i thought deleting the old Images is the easiest Way . Or do you have another suggestion ? And i tried it with your Method to delete the Images but I am getting an Acess_violence ERROR

Comment: @Philip1895 I think your images may be used in other places. When you delete the old one the pointers to them are not updated in that places and this may cause Acess_violence. So I suggest you to investigate the places where did you use this pointers.

Comment: Yes i am using them in an onClick method. As you can see in my Code i set the OnClick of the Image = ImageClick . And in Image Click i set this :       TImage *Img = dynamic_cast<TImage *>(Sender); 
ShowMessage(Img->StyleName);

Comment: means to display something.

Comment: If you use TImage as control of your form that my caused the problem.

Comment: I am getting the Pointer adress in the ImageClick Method

Comment: You mean TImageControl ?

Comment: Ok I am trying it now

Comment: @Philip1895: I have not use C++ Builder for long time and did not have access to it at that moment.

Comment: I tried it and also getting an acess violence error . But could it cohere with my imageClick Method  : TImage *Img = dynamic_cast<TImage *>(Sender);

Comment: @Philip1895: So Is the error come when you clicking?

Comment: No. the error appears on delete button . because on the create button click the images which all get created. And on an other button click i  want to delete them with the foor loop code you suggested above. I seperated it in two buttons cause its easier to test.

Comment: I got it , i just had to make the TImage *TImage[10] ; global . But in the global i cant set a variable . I just have to use numbers . problem is i dont know how many space i have to reservate for images .  the variable c is the count of images. but in global i cant use TImage *TImage[c]

Comment: thanks for  the help it finally work as i want it to !!:)

Answer (score 2):

@Mykola i pulled the example out of my code , so it is not that complicated to understand. in button2 i want to delete now all images that are on tabitem1

```
void __fastcall TForm2::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
TImage *Image[5] ;

for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
Image[i] = new TImage(this);
Image[i]->Parent = TabItem1 ;
Image[i]->Height = 20 ;
Image[i]->Width = 20 ;
Image[i]->Position->X = 10 ;
Image[i]->Position->Y = 10 ;
Image[i]->Bitmap = Image1->Bitmap ;
Image[i]->StyleName = "Something" ;
Image[i]->OnClick = ImageClick ;
}
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------  
void __fastcall TForm2::ImageClick(TObject *Sender)
{
TImage *Img = dynamic_cast<TImage *>(Sender);
ShowMessage(Img->StyleName);
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm2::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could go like this. In the header of the class you define the array and some methods:

```
int c;                            // Maximum (better as define?)
TImage *Image[];

bool CheckImagesLoaded();
void DeleteAllImages();
void CreateImage(int nIndex, AnsiString str);
void CreateAllImages();
```

Then, in the constructor you init the array:

```
c = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
{
    Image[i] = NULL;
}
```

Now you can do the check if images were already loaded:

```
bool TForm1::CheckImagesLoaded()
{
    return Image[0]!=NULL;
}
```

To delete them all:

```
void TForm1::DeleteAllImages()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
    {
        delete Image[i];
        Image[i] = NULL;
    }
}
```

Create a a single image like this (you have to expand the parameters as you need them):

```
void TForm1::CreateImage(int nIndex, AnsiString str)
{
    Image[nIndex] = new TImage(this);
    /*Image[nIndex]->Parent = BoardItem ;
    Image[nIndex]->Height = 20 ;
    Image[nIndex]->Width = 20 ;
    Image[nIndex]->Position->X = d ;  // The programm asks you the coordinate at the begining of a new loop
    Image[nIndex]->Position->Y = e ;
    Image[nIndex]->Bitmap = Icon->Bitmap ;
    Image[nIndex]->StyleName = str ;
    Image[nIndex]->OnClick = ImageClick ;
    */
}
```

And in a loop you can create all images as you like:

```
void TForm1::CreateAllImages()
{
    AnsiString str = " Test ";
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
    {
        // load data from anywhere...
        CreateImage(i, str);
    }
}
```

So, now you can operate in the Button-Event.

Delete all old Images, if existing.

Create all new Images.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    // Delete old Images, if existing
    if (CheckImagesLoaded())
    {
        DeleteAllImages();
    }

    // Create new Images
    CreateAllImages();
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Well thanks for the answer but i don't really understand the last two examples . And is it really required to do so many effort only to refresh the properties of the dynamic created Images from a database?

Comment: Can you explain? And, right, the example shows how to create and delete the image object itself. But, as Mycola wrote, faster is the way to exchange the data in the image object...

Comment: Yes i guess that might be easier and faster . I want to download some properties of an Image from a database : the blob , and the URL . For URL i am using StyleName from the Image. I am loading the blob into a stream and then into an Image on my Formular. Then load the dynamic Image->Bitmap from the Image on my Formular. in the next loop pass I am doing that again for the next line in my Database . So Image on my Form gets the new Image from next line in DB. And then the new dynamic Image gets his Bitmap again from the Image on my formular . And after clicking the Button I simply want refresh

Comment: In case someone edit his blob in DB i want to show the new blob on the refresh button click . When i terminate the app and start again i am getting the newest properties but dont want to terminate it everytime when someone edits his picture in database. Hope you understand this

Comment: So you could do it by deleting the bitmap, not the image, right?

Comment: Yes deleting Bitmap should work and after that load the new Bitmap